# Find the limit ‎ ‎$‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}((x-m)‎\Gamma_q‎(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n ‎\Gamma_q‎(k) - \Gamma_q (k+x-m‎)) ‎$

Tags: calculus, limits, special-functions

The ‎q-‎gamma function ‎‎‎‎$‎‎\Gamma‎_q‎$‎ is defined as follows‎: ‎‎

‎
‎$‎‎\Gamma‎_q(x) =‎ ‎(1-q)^{1-x} ‎‎\prod‎_{n=0}^\infty ‎‎\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q^{n+x}}‎‎‎$,
 ‎when ‎‎$‎|q|<1‎$‎. My question:

Could anyone help me calculate the ‎following ‎limit?‎
‎
‎$‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}((x-m)‎\Gamma_q‎(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n ‎\Gamma_q‎(k) - \Gamma_q (k+x-m‎)) ‎‎‎‎$, for ‎$‎m\in‎\mathbb{N}‎‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎x\geq 0‎$‎.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a finite limit.